# Dynamic UID to edit the current news item

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, uid

I use "Frontend_Editing" extension on TYPO3, to edit News items from Frontend.

How can i edit this code to change `uid` with the value of the current News item :

```
<core:contentEditable table="tx_news_domain_model_news" uid="9">
    <f:render section="content" />
</core:contentEditable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution `uid="{item.uid}"` need to be `uid="{newsItem.uid}"`

So the code is :

```
<core:contentEditable table="tx_news_domain_model_news" uid="{newsItem.uid}">
    <f:render section="content" />
</core:contentEditable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/frontend_editing/stable/InlineEditing/Index.html) of EXT:frontend_editing?

A full example for inline editing of a certain field looks like this:

```
<core:contentEditable table="{item.table}" field="{item.field}" uid="{item.uid}">
        {item.bodytext}
</core:contentEditable>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the same example that I used, but I need to change `uid="{item.uid}"` with dynamic value of the current news item.

Comment: if I add `uid="{item.uid}"` I get error : `Property "uid" can not to be empty!` So it need to be a dynamic value.